# What is the relation between the PictureBox size and the image size in pixels?

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, bitmap, designer

In the *Form Designer* of *Visual-Studio 2022* I can insert a *PictureBox*.

Are there correlations to consider between the size of the *PictureBox* and the size of the bitmap image?

Obviously I will not insert a huge bitmap into a small *PictureBox*, but are these sizes expected to be identical, or will the picture look better if they are identical?

Thanks, Paz

Comment: It depends what you want. You should research the `SizeMode` property of the control to see what can be accomplished. It's then up to you what is best in each individual situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended that you review the properties of `SizeMode` in `PictureBox`.

In Normal mode, the Image position is in the upper-left corner of the `PictureBox`, and any part of the image is cropped too large over the `PictureBox`.

StretchImage uses this value to cause the image to stretch or shrink to fit the `PictureBox`.

Zoom using this value causes the image to stretch or shrink to fit `PictureBox`.

However, the aspect ratio in the original image remains the same.

AutoSize uses this value to cause the control to resize to always fit the image.

Using this value by CenterImage causes the image to be centered in the workspace.

You can refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox.sizemode?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks).

Comment: Additionally, you could place the `PictureBox` in a `Panel` with scrollbars enabled, and add code to size the `PictureBox` to the size of the loaded image, so you can have a scrollable image.